# one ball two path svg animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, svg-animate

i want the white ball to move from straight line to first upper curve and then the ball should come to the intersection point of three path and should go to bottom curve and after it should start from first

here is my code

```
<body>
    <div class="svg-div">
      <svg width="1170" height="308" viewBox="0 0 1170 308" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M40.8965 147.5H688.896C717.623 176.877 760.593 248.871 794.526 254.664C831.194 260.923 961.644 259.629 1060.96 258.388C1163.01 258.388 1181.01 258.388 1181.01 258.388
        M717.896 145.834C795.984 152.488 833.582 56.4321 883.988 34.8068C908.778 24.1714 1067.85 27.7382 1169.9 27.7381" 
        stroke="#8CBFF1"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="ball"></div>

    <div class="integrate buttons">
      integrate time log
    </div>  
    <div class="generate buttons">
      generate invoice
    </div>  
    <div class="email-clients buttons">
      email to clients
    </div>  
    <div class="paypal buttons">
      paypal
    </div>  
    <div class="stripe buttons">
      stripe
    </div>  
  </body>
```

```
 svg {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
      }

      .ball {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        offset-path: path(
          "M40.8965 147.5H688.896C717.623 176.877 760.593 248.871 794.526 254.664C831.194 260.923 961.644 259.629 1060.96 258.388C1163.01 258.388 1181.01 258.388 1181.01 258.388"
        );
        offset-rotate: auto;
        offset-distance: 0%;
        animation: red-ball 5s linear infinite;
        animation-timing-function: steps(15, end);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0.5rem;
        left: 8.5rem;
      }

      @keyframes red-ball {
        0% {
          offset-distance: 0%;
        }
        100% {
          offset-distance: 100%;
        }
      }

      .email-clients {
        left: 48rem;
        top: 8rem;
      }

      .integrate {
        left: 10rem;
        top: 8rem;
      }
      
      .generate {
        left: 30rem;
        top: 8rem;
      }

      .stripe {
        top: 1rem;
        left: 67rem;
      }

      .paypal {
        top: 15rem;
        left: 62rem;
      }

      .buttons {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #046ACC;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 24px;
        border: 1px solid #8CBFF1;
        width: 120px;
      }

      .svg-div {
        background-color: #046ACC;
      }
```

im only seeing the ball moving to straight line but not going to upper curve but straight to bottom curve